# Post data in html dynamic table to controller with ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

this is my table in view.

```
<table class="customtable" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="width: 80px">Employee ID</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">Employee Name:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="width: 100px">Employee Type</div>
            </td>@foreach (var workDay in dayList) {
            <td>@workDay.Value
                <br>&nbsp; @workDay.Key</td>}</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>@for (int i = 0; i
        < Model.LineItems.Count; i++) { <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m =>@Model.LineItems[i].EmployeeNo)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => @Model.LineItems[i].EmployeeName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => @Model.LineItems[i].EmployeeType)</td>@for (int j = 0; j
            < Model.LineItems[i].EmployeeLineItems.Count; j++) { <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.LineItems[i].EmployeeLineItems[j].ShiftCode, MVC.Shared.Views.EditorTemplates.ShiftCodePicker)</td>}</tr>}</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to pass this to controller via ajax post method

```
function ajaxAdd() {
    var i = 0;
    var model;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        model = {
            'EmployeeId': $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.EmployeeId)").val(),
                'SignatureId': $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.SignatureId)").val(),
                'StoreId': $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.StoreId)").val(),
                'ScheduleDate': $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.ScheduleDate)").val(),
                'LineItems[0].EmployeeLineItems[1].ShiftCode': $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.LineItems[0].EmployeeLineItems[1].ShiftCode)").val()
        };
    }


    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action(MVC.WorkSchedule.ActionNames.AddNew, MVC.WorkSchedule.Name)",
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function () {

            window.location.href = "@Url.Action(MVC.WorkSchedule.ActionNames.Create, MVC.WorkSchedule.Name)";
        }
    });
}
```

when i pass the values like `$("#@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.LineItems[0].EmployeeLineItems[1].ShiftCode)").val()` i can get that value in controller method. but once i replace them with 'i' it will not work.

Is there any other way i can send this data to controller with ajax post method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the details of your models but given the mark-up and code you provided I pull out this example using `Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax` (You have to install it if you haven't yet, using Nuget is the easiest way. In the Nuget console enter `Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`. You can also use the NuGet Packages Manager).

This works as expected sending to the server (via AJAX into the action `EmployeesPost`) the new values on shift codes TextBoxes.

After install the `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` you have to add a bundle in your `BundleConfig.cs`file under the `App_Start` folder, like this:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));
```

Here are the models I create trying to reproduce yours :
(I put all these in a `EmployeeViewModels.cs` file under `Models` folder)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace ExemplesApplication.Models
    {
        public class ShiftCode
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        public class EmployeeLine
        {
            public ShiftCode ShiftCode { get; set; }
        }
        public class Employee
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<EmployeeLine> EmployeeLineItems { get; set; }

        public Employee()
        {
            EmployeeLineItems = new List<EmployeeLine>
            {
                new EmployeeLine {ShiftCode = new ShiftCode {Name = "Morning" }},
                new EmployeeLine {ShiftCode = new ShiftCode {Name = "NOON"}},
                new EmployeeLine {ShiftCode = new ShiftCode {Name = "Afternoon"}},
                new EmployeeLine {ShiftCode = new ShiftCode {Name = "evening"}},
                new EmployeeLine {ShiftCode = new ShiftCode {Name = "Night"}}
            };
        }
    }
    public class EmployeesViewModel
    {
        public bool HaveToAddRow { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> WorkDays
        {
            get
            {
                return new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"Monday", "1"},
                    {"Tuesday", "2"},
                    {"Wednesday", "3"},
                    {"Thursday", "4"},
                    {"Friday", "5"}
                };
            }
        }

        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public EmployeesViewModel()
        {
            Employees = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee {Id = 1, Name = "Robert", Type = "Engineer"},
                new Employee {Id = 2, Name = "Albert", Type = "Driver"},
                new Employee {Id = 3, Name = "Fred", Type = "Manager"},
                new Employee {Id = 4, Name = "Thomas", Type = "Sales"},
                new Employee {Id = 5, Name = "Sahra", Type = "Engineer"}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then the controller looks like this (`EmployeeController.cs`) :

```
    using ExemplesApplication.Models;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace ExemplesApplication.Controllers
    {
        public partial class EmployeeController : Controller
        {
            public virtual ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View(new EmployeesViewModel());
            }

            public virtual ActionResult EmployeesPost(EmployeesViewModel model)
            {
                if (model.HaveToAddRow)
                {
                    //add row
                    model.Employees.Add(new Employee {Id = 1, Name = "New employee", Type = "Engineer"});
                    return PartialView(MVC.Employee.Views._TableEmployees, model);
                }
                else
                {
                    // your logic to save 
                    //here

                    // render the partial view
                    return PartialView(MVC.Employee.Views._TableEmployees, model);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I created one view and one partial view :

View (`/Views/Employee/Index.cshtml`)

```
@model ExemplesApplication.Models.EmployeesViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employees";

    var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "employees-table-container", Url = Url.Action(MVC.Employee.EmployeesPost())};
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using(Ajax.BeginForm(ajaxOptions))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.HaveToAddRow)
    <div id="employee-container">
        <div id="employees-table-container">
            @Html.Partial(MVC.Employee.Views._TableEmployees, Model)
        </div>
        <input id="add-row" type="button" value="Add Row" />
        <input id="save-table"type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
}

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $form = $("form"),
                $haveToAddRowHidden = $("#HaveToAddRow");

            $("#add-row").on("click", function() {
                $haveToAddRowHidden.val(true);
                $form.submit();
            });

            $("#save-table").on("click", function () {
                $haveToAddRowHidden.val(false);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

PartialView (`/Views/Employee/_TableEmployees.cshtml`)

```
@model ExemplesApplication.Models.EmployeesViewModel

<table class="customtable" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="width: 80px">Employee ID</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">Employee Name:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="width: 100px">Employee Type</div>
            </td>
            @foreach (var workDay in Model.WorkDays)
            {
                <td>
                    @workDay.Value
                    <br>&nbsp; @workDay.Key
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Employees.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => @Model.Employees[i].Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => @Model.Employees[i].Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => @Model.Employees[i].Name)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => @Model.Employees[i].Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => @Model.Employees[i].Type)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => @Model.Employees[i].Type)
                </td>
                @for (var j = 0; j < Model.Employees[i].EmployeeLineItems.Count; j++)
                {
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Employees[i].EmployeeLineItems[j].ShiftCode, MVC.Shared.Views.EditorTemplates.ShiftCodePicker)</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally I created the `EditorTemplate` (`Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ShiftCodePicker.chtml`)

```
@model ExemplesApplication.Models.ShiftCode

@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Name, new { @class = "editor-for-shiftcode" })
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
for this requirement i need to have two buttons.
one is to add rows to table. and other one to save the table.

My issue is with the first one. 

for the Save button i am getting the values in [Httppost] method. 
       
but for the other add button which is adding rows to the Table. what i need is get the existing model which have shiftcode pickers selected. and add a new row with default shiftcodes. and pass it back to the view.
this is where i need to get the model. (I tried to add a image but it needs 10 credits :(

Comment: you can add a property to your model (say, `public bool HasToAddRow{get; set;}`) whitch you put as a Hidden on the view, and within the event click of your buttons change the value of that hidden. Then in the action (`EmployeePost`) you can have a `if` handling what you want: (`if(model.HasToAddRow){ //add row }else{ //save })

Comment: @ISP I modified my post following your comment. You can see I add a property to the model and I modified both the view and the controller to manage this new property.
Now you can add a row wen clicking to the `Add Row`button.

Comment: @ISP I also edited the Partial view to get my demo to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks.. adding that field do the trick..Thanks for you help.